# How to split string inside string array?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below is my string array :

```
 public string[] categories { get; set; }
```

Now this categories contains records like below :

```
 "categories": [
    "electronic,sports",
    "abc,pqr",
    "xyz",
  ]
```

**Input**:

```
string[] categories = { "electronic,sports", "abc,pqr", "xyz"};
```

Now I want to split values in categories and create records like this but in **categories variable only** :

So final categories variable should contain output like below:

```
"categories": [
    "electronic",
    "sports",
    "abc",
    "pqr",
    "xyz",
  ]
```

So I want my loop to run 5 times; if I loop on to categories variable and further lots of operation is done on this variable only so I don't want to take above final output in other variable.

```
 foreach (var category in categories)
 {
     //code
 }
```

Comment: What is your input? is that a part of JSON or what else?

Comment: `categories = categories.SelectMany(o => o.Split(',')).ToArray();` ?

Comment: @un-lucky:Updated my question to include sample input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and then project the result to array :

```
using System.Linq;


string[] categories = { "electronic,sports", "abc,pqr", "xyz"};
categories = categories.SelectMany(o => o.Split(',')).ToArray();

foreach(var c in categories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9OLnvc)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
electronic
sports
abc
pqr
xyz
```

Comment: Yes this worked.thank you so much for the kind help and please keep helping like this.Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try without if code;

```
        List<string> temps = new List<string>();
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            temps.AddRange(category.Split(',').ToList());
        }
        categories = temps.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
List<string> newcategories = new List<string>();
foreach(var category in categories)
{
    if(category.Contains(","))
    {
        string[] c = category.Split(',');
        newcategories.Add(c[0]);
        newcategories.Add(c[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        newcategories.Add(category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry as i said in my question that i dont want to use new variable.i want in my categories string array only

Answer (score 1):

Without linq...just using a couple foreach loops.

```
        string[] categories = new string[] { "electronic,sports", "abc,pqr", "xyz" };

        foreach(var category in categories)
        {
            foreach(var item in category.Split(','))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and please keep helping like this :)